# Please don’t make Careers programmers only in practice!

Tags: feature-request, careers

Careers will soon be [merged into Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312452/2284570).

Only two sites are concerned by this change, because there’s currently only two kind of jobs on Careers, developers and system administrators.

## Situation :

Because careers.stackoverflow.com isn't careers.stackexchange.com *(and use some of stackoverflow design)* most jobs advertised on careers *(which will become stackoverflow)* target developpers.
Of course this issue predates the current change but it will enhance targeting for developers at the expense of sysadmins. Thus making things **far worst** because there would be no longer separate site with a separate design and separate accounts

## Result of the change :

I understand you will keep encouraging posting sysadmin jobs on StackOverflow instead of careers. But such change **will definitely put a strong STOP to the idea** of advertising non developers jobs for employers.

This also means Server Fault users would need to create a Stack Overflow account even if they do nothing related to questions/answers on Stack Overflow. Those who have a Careers profile, but not a Stack Overflow account will also probably get a Stack Overflow account.

So please don’t move what remains of this feature !

### Update

***Please note this post is not seeking for discussion but for asking the removal of a feature that will disadvantage the Server Fault community.***

Comment: I think this question better fit the only public which is concerned by non programming jobs being advertised.

Comment: Already answered [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271121/please-don-t-make-careers-developers-only/271126#271126), don't feel like answering twice. I'll leave it up to the folks here to discuss the matter or not as they wish.

Comment: Hello, [any peoples having a careers profile here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271121/242800#comment879015_271126) ? an example of someone who will soon have a fresh new stackoverflow account : http://careers.stackoverflow.com/edmundwhite

Comment: Someone has already replied to your feature request in a post [elsewhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271121/please-don-t-make-careers-developers-only).

Comment: I have a careers profile thank you. I guess I just don't see this as a problem worth having a screaming fit over. If I was going to spend my energy being concerned about *something* regarding careers.se then it would be the overall scarcity of sysadmin jobs, not how se presents those jobs to the community.

Comment: @RobM : read this post again, this is not about how se present those jobs but how the scarcity of sysadmin jobs will be far lower than it is currently. Please upvote if you think they should not be scarer than now.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say, I just disagree...

Comment: I've started a [discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313459/what-about-jobs-for-sysadmins) on MSO, because it seems [MSO is now the official place to discuss Careers/Jobs issues](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312744/is-the-careers-meta-going-to-move-from-mse-to-mso).

Comment: @Massimo which was asked after that question

Comment: @user2284570 I asked the question on MSO (and posted a pointer question here) because discussions about Careers/Jobs are being moved to MSO, so that's the place to talk about it now.

Comment: @Massimo : this question don’t seek for discussion but ask for a change.

Comment: @user2284570 You don't understand. Meta is not for "asking for change", but for discussion. So you're whole premise is flawed. You're using the tool wrong.

Comment: @Wesley : so what is the purpose of the`feature request`tag ? :-)

Comment: @user2284570 To discuss a feature request.

Comment: @Wesley : Strange, it can be used without the`discussion`tag. It is even part of the 5 mandatory tags choice. :-)

Comment: @user2284570 You're missing the point. The tag is there to give the question topicality, and then it's discussed below. There is no "this is not for discussion" option. This question is a duplicate and should be closed, and judging by the close votes it will be closed shortly.

Comment: @Wesley : Even if it was a duplicate of [http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8552/203649](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8552/203649) it was asked earlier and isn’t a pointer to a question. But it there’s siply a misunderstanding : it talk about the same thing, but ask a different thing.