# What about jobs for system administrators?

Tags: discussion, careers

**Please don't close this question as duplicate, and also please don't post answers here. This is only a pointer to remind ServerFault users that this topic is being discussed elsewhere, because it seems [MSO is now the official place to discuss Careers/Jobs issues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312744/is-the-careers-meta-going-to-move-from-mse-to-mso).**

The issue: now that [Careers is being fully integrated into StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow), what about jobs for sysadmins?

The discussion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313459/what-about-jobs-for-system-administrators.

Comment: If this is just a pointer... Why can't we close it? Closing =\= deleting.

Comment: Are closed questions still shown as suggestions if someone tries to post a new one with a similar topic?

Comment: I'm not 100%, but I believe so, yes.

Comment: The topic is actually more relevant to SF (and thus MSF), but MSO seems to be the right place to discuss it. Hence this pointer...

Comment: [related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271121/242800).

Comment: All linked questions (including the ones marked as possible duplicates) are indeed related; but what I'm *exactly* trying to do is gathering all discussions about this issue in a single place (the question on MSO), and only leave this pointer question here to say "the official discussion is there". As I said *right in the first row", please don't mark *this one* as a duplicate: the opposite should be done. Thank you.

Comment: @Massimo : if this is just a pointer, the`feature request`tag is irrelevant.

Comment: @user2284570 Agreed, tag removed.

Comment: @Massimo : [thank you](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8542/203649).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The relevant discussion is here:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313459/what-about-jobs-for-system-administrators.**

---

The rest of this answer is completely useless, so feel free to skip it. The reason I'm posting additional words is because otherwise the answer [would be considered "trivial" and converted to a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment), and it looks like adding a bunch of text is the only way to be sure (other than [nuking it from orbit](http://nukeitfromorbit.com), of course).