# Change the duplicate excerpt

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

Currently,

> This question has been asked **before** and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question.

But there are some legitimate cases were it’s [the question that was asked earlier which is closed](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8542/please-don-t-make-careers-programmers-only)

So what about removing the reference to the past. It also worth to note every closed posts aren’t questions.

> A post like this one with an answer exist on this site. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question.

Answer (score 10):

For the reader, it's **extremely** irrelevant which question has been asked first. While it might be more correct, the "problem" just doesn't matter enough to warrant any action.

Honestly, this appears to be more about you whining because you posted first but your post has been closed and Massimo's hasn't...